# Alternate pgm for the given pgm without using function

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lower_string(char*);


    int main()
   {
      char string[100];

      printf("Enter a string to convert it into lower case\n");
      gets(string);

      lower_string(string);

      printf("Entered string in lower case is \"%s\"\n", string);

      return 0;
    }

    void lower_string(char *string)
     {
       while(*string)
       {
       if ( *string >= 'A' && *string <= 'Z' ) 
       { 
           *string = *string + 32;
        } 
        string++;
       }
}
```

In this program what if i replace `*string` with `string[]`?
can anyone help me in writing the above program without using any function?
And please explain what does this mean    while(*str)  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void lower_string(char *string);
```

and

```
void lower_string(char string[]);
```

are equivalent in C.  A parameter of type `char []` is *adjusted* to type `char *`.

Of course when `string` is the operand of the `*` operator like in:

```
while (*string)
```

then you cannot change it to `string[]` as `*` here is the indirection operator and not a part of a type name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two, because when an array is passed to a function, it <strike>decays</strike> adjusts to a pointer.

I wouldn't write such code and then tag it `C++`, because `string` is a standard library class name.

Comment: There is no decay or conversion being made for a function parameter, C says the parameter is *adjusted*.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it. But isn't decay defined as "loss of type/size"?

Answer (score 1):

**[C-FAQ: Q-6.4](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html):**

> Since arrays decay immediately into pointers, an array is never actually passed to a function. You can pretend that a function receives an array as a parameter, and illustrate it by declaring the corresponding parameter as an array:
>
> ```
> void f(char a[])
> { ... }
> ```
>
> **Interpreted literally, this declaration would have no use, so the compiler turns around and pretends that you'd written a pointer declaration**, since that's what the function will in fact receive:
>
> ```
> void f(char *a)
> { ... }
> ```
>
> There's nothing particularly wrong with talking about a function as if it ``receives'' an array, if the function is traditionally used to operate on arrays, or if the parameter is naturally treated within the function as an array.
>   **This conversion of array-like declarators into pointers holds only within function formal parameter declarations, nowhere else.**

Comment: The danger of using `void f(char a[])` is with later readers/maintainers who don't grok all the details of the language. They will be tricked into believing that `a` is an array, and quite likely try to use it in a `sizeof`. It's a nice little trap that can very easily be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol    [] is basically equivalent to `*` in some way.
You can accept `char[]` and still treat it as a pointer with `*` and you can accept a `char*` as a parameter and access it with `[]` as a regular array - it's exactly the same.
You're always getting a pointer to that spot in memory, when it's an array defined with `[]` though, the pointer will be constant (can't deference it, only access where it's pointing to).
When you're declaring an array using `char str[100];` you're actually declaring a `const char*` named `str` and pointing to a memory area in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

They are pretty much the same thing. For example,

```
sz[x];
```

is short for

```
*(sz + x);
```

However, when you write `char *sz;`, all yau are getting is a pointer. Wen you write `char sz[size];`, you are getting an array also. See haccks' answer.